# search the pattern and replace the value in a file

Tags: linux, text-processing, date, command-history

/home/digadm02/.bash_history:#1520325239
/home/digadm02/.bash_history:sudo su

I have these kind of lines in file test.txt. I have to search the pattern of "#1520325239" and replace them with the value which I get from the command 'date -d @1520325239'. there are many lines like this. I have to read each line and replace it in the same file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you trying to clean your own mess from history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, the timestamp isn't just one, but many on similar lines. This script should do replacement you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get timestamps from the file
dates=`sed -e '1,$s/^.*#\(.*\) \/.*/\1/' /tmp/test.txt`

for date in $dates
do
    # get human readable format from timestamp
    newdate=`date -d @${date}`
    # replace timestamp with human readable date
    sed -i "1,\$s/\#$date/$newdate/" /tmp/test.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command as per your need

```
sed -i s/#1520325239/$(date -d @1520325239)/g .bash_history
```

Comment: could you try to provide a bit more explantation on this expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Use sed

`sed -i "/#1520325239/c$(date -d @1520325239)" test.txt`

-i will modify the file in place. Omit the "i" to test your results first.